# Parsing automatically gerenerated JSON file

Tags: java, json, eclipse, ubuntu

I am totally new on working with JSON.

Currently, I am processing JSON files, which are automatically generated from a device. The file contains huge number of objects and looks like the following:

```
{"age":13,"name":"Alan","Acc":[12,25,60]}
{"age":33,"name":"Dave","Acc":NULL}
{"age":18,"name":"Sara","Acc":[2,3,4]}
...
```

I went through some tutorials and understood JSON notations/syntax shall not be like the files that I'm working with.

I am trying to parse these files using Java ***[JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)***, but I get  error after the following line of code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/alan/test.json"));
```

The error is:

> Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({)

I would be appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Cheers,

Alan

Comment: What you are showing is not a valid JSON file

Comment: can you plz show full JSON which you are receiving

Comment: Valid json looks like: `[{
 "age": 13,
 "name": "Alan",
 "Acc": [12, 25, 60]
}, {
 "age": 33,
 "name": "Dave",
 "Acc": "NULL"
}, {
 "age": 18,
 "name": "Sara",
 "Acc": [2, 3, 4]
}]`

Comment: So your options are to manipulate the JSON "file" to be valid JSON.  Or to parse just one line at a time.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response! Now I modified the file like the one @Jens suggested and get "Unexpected character (N) at position xxx"!

Comment: Do you have set the NULL in double qoutes?

Comment: @Jens Oopss! my fault ! forgot to do it. thanks and sorry again! :)